# Filter xml using xpath and linq (price with decimal separator and thousands separator spanish) VB. NET

Tags: vb.net, linq, xpath

I'm trying to filter the results of a xml file. One of the fields I've been requested to filter is the attribute price of each node. The problem is the xml is from a spanish source and the prices are with decimal separator being , instead of . and thousands separator is , instead of .

I'm trying to get an xml file filtered where only nodes withprices lower than one supplied appear.

The xml structure is:

```
<RoomStays>
    <RoomStay InfoSource="" Price="201,60" Discount="0" MealPlan="Sólo alojamiento" MealPlanId="1" Provider="Marsol" ProviderId="3" HotelName="HOTEL LA ESTACION" Rating="" Latitud="" Longitud=""> 
    <RoomStay InfoSource="" Price="1.234,75" Discount="0" MealPlan="Sólo alojamiento" MealPlanId="1" Provider="Marsol" ProviderId="3" HotelName="HOTEL LA ESTACION" Rating="" Latitud="" Longitud=""> 
    ....More nodes
</RoomStays>
```

I've tried to filter using XPath and Linq2Xml. I've come to the conclussion I have to replace , with . and . with , but I get 0 results.

With values below 1000 where there is only , I've got it using:

```
doc.XPathSelectElements(./RoomStays/RoomStay[translate(@Price,',','.')<=256.78])
```

But when there are prices above 1000 with thousands separator . it doesn't work, so I tried:

```
doc.XPathSelectElements(./RoomStays/RoomStay[translate(translate(@Price,'.',''),',','.')<=256.78])
```

But it returns 0 results (I tried to use replace function instead of translate to remove the . characters but I get an exception).

So I'm stuck, if someone could help me even if there are another way of getting this (not necessarily XPath).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use**:

```
translate(@Price, ',.', '.')
```

This deletes any `'.'` and replaces any `','` with a `'.'`

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
      "/RoomStays/RoomStay[not(translate(@Price, ',.', '.') > 256.78)]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<RoomStays>
    <RoomStay InfoSource="" Price="201,60" Discount="0" MealPlan="Sólo alojamiento" MealPlanId="1" Provider="Marsol" ProviderId="3" HotelName="HOTEL LA ESTACION" Rating="" Latitud="" Longitud=""/>
    <RoomStay InfoSource="" Price="1.234,75" Discount="0" MealPlan="Sólo alojamiento" MealPlanId="1" Provider="Marsol" ProviderId="3" HotelName="HOTEL LA ESTACION" Rating="" Latitud="" Longitud=""/>
    ....More nodes
</RoomStays>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated and the selected nodes (just one in this case) are copied to the output**:

```
<RoomStay InfoSource="" Price="201,60" Discount="0" MealPlan="Sólo alojamiento" MealPlanId="1" Provider="Marsol" ProviderId="3" HotelName="HOTEL LA ESTACION" Rating="" Latitud="" Longitud="" />
```